# How to stop Selenium to allow manual captcha resolution?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to start my Selenium script on a login page, wait for 30 seconds so I can manually resolve a captcha, and once the login is successful, start the actual work automation work.

I'm using the code below, and it works ok up to the line where it enter the email.

I supposed that this code will wait in a sort of pooling until it sees the H4 element with certain text in it (login successful), but it throws an exception when the element is not found.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL");
var loginEmail = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LOGINTextBTTN"));
loginEmail.SendKeys("myEmail");  //this line works

IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(@"//h4[text()='H4 Text']")));  //this lines fails with an exception

Console.WriteLine(firstResult.GetAttribute("textContent"));
```

Comment: Fluent wait would be ideal way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Write the code

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ; // Wait for 60 Sec.

WebElement firstResult = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(@"//h4[text()='H4 Text']")));

Or
You can use Fluentwait

Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver).withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this a while back. The way I solved was with sleep:

```
time.sleep(seconds need to solve) #for me it was around 60ish seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
import code
code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

Then Ctrl+D out after you solve the captcha